# changing DNS setting doesn't seem to have any effect

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, dns, proxy

I am currently on Windows 10, and trying to use dnscrypt to proxy my DNS lookup from port 53 to some other port so it will bypass transparent DNS.

however, when I change my windows DNS setting to 127.0.0.1 (so dnscrypt will procy it somewhere else) the DNS seems to just ignore my setting and do some dnsquerying to my ISP DNS. Even when I deliberately put some IP that has no computer on it(192.168.1.230), the DNS just works on the ISP setting. I have turned off DHCP setting on my wireless router and modem. Can someone explain to me why this is happening? and how to make my computer recognize the setting i put in the DNS field?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Turned out I have an IPV6 address as my DNS, and it perform the lookup for me. after disabling it, all went as expected